# Sending data through controller, in mvc pattern using ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

Using knockout I am trying to send data, from my UI to the controller. This is the javascript used to send my ajax request(PUT)

```
var model = new Object();
model.StudentID = "";
model.ActiveProgram = "";
model.ProgramDesc = self.programData();
model.Cohorts = self.associationData();
model.LoadIntent = self.loadIntentData();
model.Francophone = self.frenchData();
model.Gender = self.genderData();

    $.ajax({
        url: putStudentRegRequirementsUrl,
        type: "PUT",
        contentType: jsonContentType,
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(model),
        //jsonData:model,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#notificationHost').notificationCenter('addNotification', { message: "Updated.", type: "info" });
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            if (jqXHR.status != 0)
            {
                $('#notificationHost').notificationCenter('addNotification', { message: "Unable to update registration requirement.", type: "error"});
            }
        }
    });
```

But when I debug it to see my controller, the string comming in is blank. This is my controller

```
 [HttpPut]
    public async Task<JsonResult> UpdateRegistrationRequirementAsync(string regRequirementJson)
    {
        try
        {
            var regRequirementModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RegistrationRequirement>(regRequirementJson);
            var response = await ServiceClient.L09PutRegistrationRequirementAsync(CurrentUser.PersonId, regRequirementModel);
            return Json(response);
        }
        catch( Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Debug(ex, "Error updating Registration Requirement for user failed.");
            Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
            return Json("Error updating Registration Requirement.");
        }       
    }
```

Comment: Your Model is an object , and your controller is expecting a string .

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake when typing into stack overflow, corrected with sending model as a json

Comment: Try doing this : UpdateRegistrationRequirementAsync([FromBody]string regRequirementJson)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Action will parse parameters from client by its name, so you need to pass parameter with name `regRequirementJson` contains your json. So change this line

```
data: JSON.stringify(model)
```

to

```
data: { regRequirementJson: JSON.stringify(model) }
```

and remove `contentType: jsonContentType`.

Or you can try another way. Since ASP.NET can deserialize json by itself you can keep your js code as is and update your controller to

```
[HttpPut]
public async Task<JsonResult> UpdateRegistrationRequirementAsync(RegistrationRequirement regRequirementModel )
{
    try
    {
        var response = await ServiceClient.L09PutRegistrationRequirementAsync(CurrentUser.PersonId, regRequirementModel);
        return Json(response);
    }
    catch( Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.Debug(ex, "Error updating Registration Requirement for user failed.");
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        return Json("Error updating Registration Requirement.");
    }
```

Comment: When trying to call the controller, it doesn't reach this method however anymore.

Comment: @Jseb I've updated my answer.
And this is good you managed to make the code work.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are sending a "RegistrationRequirement" object then in your controller you can do it this way :

```
[HttpPut]
    public async Task<JsonResult> UpdateRegistrationRequirementAsync(RegistrationRequirement registrationRequirement)
    {
        try
        {
            var response = await ServiceClient.L09PutRegistrationRequirementAsync(CurrentUser.PersonId, registrationRequirement);
            return Json(response);
        }
        catch( Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Debug(ex, "Error updating Registration Requirement for user failed.");
            Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
            return Json("Error updating Registration Requirement.");
        }       
    }
```